# What's the better syntax using some() on a Backbone collection to find attr duplicates?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, iteration, underscore.js

So, normally I do like this:

```
var duplicate = this.model.collection.some(function(model){
   return (model.get('hook') == h);
});
```

Fine. But in backbone docs, under collection's underscore methods, I find this:

*'Most methods can take an object or string to support model-attribute-style predicates'*

So I imagined I could refactor the above like this:

```
var duplicate = this.model.collection.some({'hook':h});
```

But it doesn't work. So what does exactly mean that doc's statement?

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire sentence :) Most methods can take an object or string to support model-attribute-style predicates **or a function that receives the model instance as an argument**. In this case it's the latter and it takes a function. `sortBy` is an example of a function that can take both. Always refer to the underscore docs for these methods.

Comment: Ah ok, in Italian a sentence like that means somewhat that BOTH the possibilities are viable for EVERY method (yes I know, not strict logic here.. ;)). Now it's clear.